# how to create graphics in Quicksight without aggregations

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I'm new to Quicksight, I want to make a simple graph with "time" on the X axis and "Pm" (int) on the Y axis.

I take "time" and drag it to the X axis, then I drag "Pm" to Value, but here Pm (Sum) appears with "Aggregate" and I only need the value of Pm. which is recorded every 5 minutes.
How can I do this to solve this?
Or where can I find an example or tutorial?

It is an IoT application, the devices send sensor data to aws IoT Core => IoT Analytics => Quicksight.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to render the data as a line chart, scatter plot or something else?
It is worth noting that QuickSight doesn't know how your data is recorded and it needs to know what to do if there are 2, 3 or even more rows with the same "time" value. If you know that you should not have more than a single row with the same time, then the fact that QuickSight is doing any aggregation should not matter.
In situations where you might have more than 1 row with a single value, you might want to use Average, Max or Min to aggregate the values (this really depends on the data you are using in the chart and what information is important for you).

To be able to render every single record in QuickSight, you need to add a field that is unique (such as a record id).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, here I show you the data that I have in the dataset and I think that with your response I reflect and I am closer to the solution.
The graphic I want is line.
The date: time field is unique for each temperature value.
regards